# jquery fadeout div after 5 seconds to end of session

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here i need fadeout `#not-count` div after 5 seconds to end session,

if i fadeout done, after that it will never appear if i reload or move to another, untill the session complete

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
       $('#notify-comet').on('click', function(e){
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#not-count').fadeOut('fast');
            }, 1000); 
       })
    })
```

How can i do this using jQuery?

Comment: Use a cookie value or localstorage to save the state.

Comment: remove the 2nd block of document ready . that's a duplicate

Comment: Do you mean you are trying to implement a "do not show me this again" function?  But only for the current "session"?

Comment: once fadeout is done, i dont want that to appear untill the session is over

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to have two doc ready blocks and you can do this for 5 seconds:

```
}, 5*1000);
```

*if i fadeout done, after that it will never appear if i reload or move to another, untill the session complete*

For this you can make use of cookie or localstorage.

Comment: You can create a cookie with some value like `clicked` and in the doc ready block you can check if any cookie with value `clicked` is available if do then just `.toggle(false)` to hide.

Comment: You can take it from here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie